# Why combine http module with express module

Tags: node.js

Hello guys i'm new to node js and started researching and working on some tutorials. I just want a better understanding or clarification on a doubt i had. So i came across the in built module `http`. This helps in creating a a basic web server. Now `express` module is a web framework that is built on top the `http module` that makes it easy using a fully wedged web server without reinventing the wheel. Now I came across this code:

```
var express = require( 'express' )
, http = require("http")
http.createServer( options, function(req,res)
{
  app.handle( req, res );
 } ).listen(8080);
```

But in express one could simply just do this

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening on ' + 8080);});
```

What's the difference between both? Don't they both accomplish the same thing. If not what's the difference and advantage of using the first approach. Should one adhere to the first approach as it's a good programming practice. That's my doubt as i just want a clear understanding if there's any difference.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry typo errofixed and updated. Thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's what i thought but i have seen examples where they combine both

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why combine http module with express module

There's really no reason to create your own http server using the `http` module.  Express will just do that for you with `app.listen()` just fine and save you little bit of typing.

If you were creating an `https` server, then you would need to use the `https` module and pass security credentials to `https.createServer(...)` in order to create a properly configured server.  Express does not have the ability to create a properly configured https server for you automatically.

---

If you look at the [Express code in GitHub for `app.listen()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e5ec966b2f068e935ea1b33374fac133dd06cdc8/lib/application.js#L615), it shows this:

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

So, there's really no difference (other than a little less typing) when you use `app.listen()` or create your own http server and then use `app` as the listener to that server.

---

So, these two code snippets are identical in function:

```
var app = require('express')();
app.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("hello");       
});
```

The above code is functionally identical to:

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("hello");       
});
```

Of course, if you're trying to set up https servers or add custom options to the `.createServer()` method, then you will set up your own server first and then pass `app` to it as the listener.  `app.listen(...)` is just a shortcut when the default `http.createServer()` works fine.

Comment: so its more for customization

Comment: @user3497437 - I added more to my answer to show you two examples that are identical in function.  You would typically only need to use `http.createServer()` if you need to pass custom options when creating the server.

Comment: @jfrend00 i think u meant 'res.send' not 'req.send'.

Comment: @user3497437 - Yes, I fixed.